# Narration and Running balance in Tally XML Ledger request

Tags: xml, post, request

How to get narration and running balance using following Tally XML SOAP request

```
<ENVELOPE>
<HEADER>
<TALLYREQUEST>Export Data</TALLYREQUEST>
</HEADER>
<BODY>
<EXPORTDATA>
<REQUESTDESC>
<REPORTNAME>Ledger Vouchers</REPORTNAME>
<STATICVARIABLES>
<SVCURRENTCOMPANY>My Company</SVCURRENTCOMPANY
<SVEXPORTFORMAT>$$SysName:XML</SVEXPORTFORMAT
<LEDGERNAME>Ledger Name</LEDGERNAME>
<SVFROMDATE>01-APR-2015</SVFROMDATE>
<SVTODATE>30-Apr-2015</SVTODATE>
</STATICVARIABLES>
</REQUESTDESC>
</EXPORTDATA>
</BODY>
</ENVELOPE>
```

Comment: What language are you writing to interact with your XML ?

Comment: Welcome on StackOverflow! Please add some more details on what you already tried, the problems you are encountering, some relevant code and so on. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) are some hints to make a good questione

Comment: I am using  PHP  Curl  for posting XML to Tally.

Answer (score 0):

@Sameer Grover use collection to get data as

```
<COLLECTION NAME=\"MyLedgerVchrBackupColl\" ISMODIFY=\"No\" ISFIXED=\"No\" ISINITIALIZE=\"No\" ISOPTION=\"No\" ISINTERNAL=\"No\">
 <TYPE>Voucher</TYPE>
 <NativeMethod>VoucherNumber, narration</NativeMethod>
 <Method>cmpName    :##SVCurrentCompany</Method> 
 <METHOD>VSPLVchDate:\$Date</METHOD>
 <METHOD>VSPLVchAmount:\$Amount</METHOD>
</COLLECTION>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<ENVELOPE>
<HEADER>
<TALLYREQUEST>Export Data</TALLYREQUEST>
</HEADER>
<BODY>
<EXPORTDATA>
<REQUESTDESC>
<REPORTNAME>Ledger Vouchers</REPORTNAME>
<STATICVARIABLES>
<SVCURRENTCOMPANY>My Company</SVCURRENTCOMPANY
<SVEXPORTFORMAT>$$SysName:XML</SVEXPORTFORMAT
<LEDGERNAME>Ledger Name</LEDGERNAME>
<ExplodeNarrFlag>YES</ExplodeNarrFlag>
<SVFROMDATE>01-APR-2015</SVFROMDATE>
<SVTODATE>30-Apr-2015</SVTODATE>
</STATICVARIABLES>
</REQUESTDESC>
</EXPORTDATA>
</BODY>
</ENVELOPE>
```

In STATICVARIABLES add the line ExplodeNarrFlag as YES to SHOW NARRATIONS

I used this page to find this and other explode flags. These explode flags work with tally reports instead of fetch.
http://tdlexpert.com/index.php?threads/php-xml-tally-integration.3369/